# Id could not be removed when attached multiple entities with the same Id

Tags: c#, winforms, ef-core-7.0

I have three class GdsReceptionBlackProduct, Employee and Customer

```
public partial class GdsReceptionBlackProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee? CreatedByNavigation { get; set; }
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<GdsReceptionBlackProduct> entity)
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.CreatedByNavigation).WithMany(p => p.CreatedBy)
    .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.IdEmployee)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedBy)
    .HasConstraintName("GDSReceptionBlackProduct_Employee_CreatedBy");
    entity.Navigation(e => e.CreatedByNavigation).AutoInclude();
}  

public partial class Employee
{
    public string IdEmployee { get; set; } = null!;
    public int? FkCountry { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GdsReceptionBlackProduct> CreatedBy { get; } = new List<GdsReceptionBlackProduct>();
}
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> entity)
{
    entity.HasOne(d => d.Country)
        .WithMany(p => p.Employees)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.FkCountry)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Employee_Country");
    entity.Navigation(e => e.Country).AutoInclude();
}
public partial class Customer
{
    public int? Fkcountry { get; set; }
    public virtual Country? Country { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GdsReceptionBlackProduct> GdsReceptionBlackProduct { get; } = new List<GdsReceptionBlackProduct>();
}
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> entity)
{
    entity.Navigation(e => e.Country).AutoInclude();
}
```

I am using unit of work with repository pattern and DI so in FrmGDSReceptionBlackProduct I use it like this

```
public FrmGDSReceptionBlackProduct(GdsReceptionBlackProductService gdsReceptionBlackProductService,
                                       CustomerService customerService)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.gdsReceptionBlackProductService = gdsReceptionBlackProductService;
    this.customerService = customerService;
}
```

When I try to remove GdsReceptionBlackProduct

```
await gdsReceptionBlackProductService.RemoveGdsReceptionBlackProductAsync(Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text));
public virtual async Task<bool> RemoveAsync(object id)
{
    T? exist = await dbSet.FindAsync(id);
    if (exist == null) throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(RemoveAsync)} entity must not be null");
    dbSet.Remove(exist);
    return true;
}
```

I get this error message

> id could not be removed: The instance of entity type 'Country' cannot
> be tracked because another instance with the key value '{IdCountry:
> 1}'
> is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

when I comment the below line of code

```
entity. Navigation(e => e.CreatedByNavigation).AutoInclude();
```

and I trying to remove the GdsReceptionBlackProduct entity it removed successfully.
I am using AutoInclude to show the properties names in grid view.
All CRUD operations are in the same form.
How can I fix this issue?
**Update**
this is the constructor of my generic repository

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>, IDisposable where T : class

{
    protected SIMContext _context;
    internal DbSet<T> dbSet;
    public GenericRepository(SIMContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        dbSet = context. Set<T>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Richard Deeming](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=34187) I get the [answer](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5362367/Id-could-not-be-removed-when-attached-multiple-ent)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Entity Framework Core is opening two connections to the database for the same entity instance at the same time and also trying to track both concurrently. When you `.AutoInclude` the country entity, the 1st tracking begins and when you use the `RemoveAsync` method, the 2nd tracking begins. Your solution would be to not track the Country entity at one of them, so you should use `.AsNoTracking` :

```
public virtual async Task<bool> RemoveAsync(object id)
{
    PropertyInfo? idProperty = typeof(T).GetProperty("Id");
    if (idProperty == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"Entity type {typeof(T).Name} does not have an 'Id' property.");

    T? exist = await dbSet.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => idProperty.GetValue(e).Equals(id));
    if (exist == null) throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(RemoveAsync)} entity must not be null");
    dbSet.Remove(exist);
    

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I get this error message:   HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The LINQ expression 'DbSet<GdsReceptionBlackProduct>()
    .Where(g => __idProperty_0.GetValue(g).Equals(__id_1))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Comment: I have already use NoTracking in my repository:    protected SIMContext _context;
    internal DbSet<T> dbSet;
    public GenericRepository(SIMContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        dbSet = context. Set<T>();
    }